# Cannot select features to install from SQL Server 2005 SP4 installation process

Tags: sql-server-2005, upgrade, permissions, service-pack

**The issue:** I cannot select MSSQLSERVER from the feature list I want to update as part of the SQL Server 2005 x64 Service Pack 4 installation process. 
Please note exe file is being raised from C:\ with full administrador privilegies.

[image]

**Server details**: Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard x64 bits 
**SQL Server details**: Microsoft SQL Server 2005 - 9.00.5294.00 (X64) (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) 
**Service Package Details**: SQLServer2005SP4-KB2463332-x64-ENU.exe

I have spent the last hour trying to identify where the issue is or similar experiencies over internet but I didn't get it until now. 
Any comments will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: so, you put a checkmark next to "MSSQLSERVER" and **what** happens?

Answer (score 3):

You are running SQL Server build 9.00.5294.00 that is more current than SP4 which is 9.00.5000. Your server has already been updated. (http://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.com/) 
(Build 7601: Service Pack 1) is the version of the operating system.